# serverless DeployCustomS31 Access point ARN region is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework, serverless

When deploying a Stack to AWS at some point I get an error and the deployment fails and rollbacks. In the Stack's Console Event pane the first error states `FancyStuffCustomS31` in `Logical ID` field and the reason is `Failed to create resource. Access point ARN region is empty` and status `CREATE_FAILED`.

I didn't define any S3 Bucket like that, so I'm assuming it's created by the serverless framework. So I peeped into the `.serverless` directory and get the following snippet:

```
"FancyStuffCustomS31": {
  "Type": "Custom::S3",
  "Version": 1,
  "DependsOn": [
    "FancyStuffLambdaFunction",
    "CustomDashresourceDashexistingDashs3LambdaFunction"
  ],
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "CustomDashresourceDashexistingDashs3LambdaFunction",
        "Arn"
      ]
    },
    "FunctionName": "funstufftest-dev-FancyStuff",
    "BucketName": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "binRepo",
        "Arn"
      ]
    },
    "BucketConfigs": [
      {
        "Event": "s3:ObjectCreated:*",
        "Rules": []
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

(No wonder my Lambda Function is called `FancyStuff`)

I'm guessing that at some point it's trying to create an access point to that S3 Bucket to upload the code and not specifying the region in the arn, but don't really know for sure.

Tried deleting and recreating the stack from scratch, changing names, etc.
Currently the only plugin I'm using is `serverless-sam`. These are my versions:

```
$ sls version
Framework Core: 1.77.0
Plugin: 3.6.18
SDK: 2.3.1
Components: 2.33.0
$ npm version
{
  npm: '6.14.7',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  cldr: '36.0',
  http_parser: '2.9.3',
  icu: '65.1',
  llhttp: '2.0.4',
  modules: '72',
  napi: '5',
  nghttp2: '1.40.0',
  node: '12.16.2',
  openssl: '1.1.1e',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '12.1',
  uv: '1.34.2',
  v8: '7.8.279.23-node.34',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your serverless.yml file to the question?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is simpler than I thought (big surprise):

1/ Specify bucket name only, no arn decoration on the name at all, no accesspoint etc.

2/ Add the region to which the lambda is deployed in the provider section at the top of your serverless.yml file.